# СИ Считать из файла слова и записать их в структуру

Tags: c, файлы

**Нужно считать текст из файла, разделить его на отдельные слова и записать в уже имеющуюся структуру**
Моя проблема в том, что при записи в структуру я получаю на выходе **дубликаты последнего словa**. Как переписать программу, чтобы она работала корректно??

Заранее спасибо!

Моя программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "my_list.h"
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 81

void main() {
  my_list *list = my_list_init(); //выделяю память для моей структуры

  FILE *src = fopen("C:\\c\\first_in.txt", "r");
  char str[N]; // N = 81
  int i = 0;
  char m[15];


  while (fgets (str,N,src) != NULL){

    char *token = strtok(str, " \n\t?!.,;:()");
    char *mp =strcpy(m,token);
    while (token != NULL) {
      my_list_insert(list,mp,i); //добавляю в мою структуру
        token = strtok(NULL," \n\t?!.,;:()");
        i++;
          }
      }
for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++) {   ///вывожу данные структуры
  printf("%s\n",(char*)(my_list_get(list,k)));
}
}
```

Файл **first_in txt**:

```
A

very
 
short

example
```

**Вывод который я получаю**:

```
example

example

example

example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, в своей структуре вы храните только указатели на строку, которые ей передаете. А передаете вы один и тот же указатель на строку

```
char m[15];
```

которую перезаписываете.

Либо меняйте принцип своего списка и храните в нем само слово, а не указатель, либо передавайте каждый раз новый указатель, получая его, например, с помощью `strdup()`. Только не забывайте потом, по окончании работы, освобождать выделенную этой функцией память.

И еще - из каждой строки вы *многократно* берете только *первое* слово, остальные игнорируя:

```
while (token != NULL) {
  my_list_insert(list,mp,i); //добавляю в мою структуру
    token = strtok(NULL," \n\t?!.,;:()");
    i++;
      }
```

Вы всякий раз добавляете все то же самое первое слово - `mp`, просто игнорируя новые значения `token` - их вы никуда не копируете и не вносите.

И еще - все же, как по мне, бывают слова и длиннее 14 символов...

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!